# Move input field on top of span

Tags: html, css

I've a span as a label for my inputfield. The label goes above the input field when selected.

My problem is that when you try to click on the input field, the label is 'in front' of the inputfield and blocks you from selecting it.

I tried fixing it using z-indexes but this doesn't seem to work.

Can somebody help me with getting the input field in front of the span?

```css
#input {
  color: #686868;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-width: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5dce3;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

#input:focus {
  border-color: #1F76BC;
}

#label {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.99);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.075,.82,.165,1);
  transition-duration: .5s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  bottom: 6px;
  color: #8792a1;
}

.container:focus-within #label {
    transform: translate3d(0,-26px,0);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.99);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <span id="label">Provincie</span>
   <input type="text" id="input" value="" size="40"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `label` instead of `span` and your `input` will be well clickable, regardless of the location of the placeholder

```js
input = document.querySelector("#input");
label = document.querySelector(".container > label");

input.addEventListener("change", function () {
    if (this.value !== "") {
        label.style.transform = "translate3d(0, -26px, 0)";
    } else {
        label.style.transform = "";
    }
});
```

```css
#input {
    color: #686868;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-width: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d5dce3;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

#input:focus {
    border-color: #1f76bc;
}

label {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    bottom: 6px;
    color: #8792a1;
}

.container:focus-within label {
    transform: translate3d(0, -26px, 0);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <label for="input">Provincie</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" value="" size="40" />
</div>
```

Comment: I kinda liked this solution but one small issue, when you type the text in the input the label will sit behind the entered value, I am not sure OP needs that and doesn't look good from UI perspective, may be you have to put the label behind the text?

Comment: @Manjuboyz, thank you for enjoying my solution :) I just checked my solution, and yes, you are right, and I did not consider this point. Placeholder should be left behind the text. We'll have to fix it.

Comment: @Manjuboyz the label will be on top of the input field when a value has been entered (which already works) but I left that part out for for simplicity's sake :)

Comment: @DaanSeuntjens cool then you got yourselves an answer then :)

Comment: @Manjuboyz, i wrote a small script to adjust the placeholder. Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

please add this style.

```
#input{
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```css
#input {
  color: #686868;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-width: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5dce3;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
}

#input:focus {
  border-color: #1F76BC;
}

#label {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.99);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.075,.82,.165,1);
  transition-duration: .5s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  bottom: 6px;
  color: #8792a1;
}

.container:focus-within #label {
    transform: translate3d(0,-26px,0);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.99);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <span id="label">Provincie</span>
   <input type="text" id="input" value="" size="40"> 
</div>
```

Comment: This **quite simple** and **smoothly** label move to top while clicking input field @Daan Seuntjens check this only add two style `position:relative` and some `z-index:999;` // higher z-index value

Answer (score 1):

Something like this??

```css
#input {
  color: #686868;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-width: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5dce3;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

#input:focus {
  border-color: #1F76BC;
}

#label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .99);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
  transition-duration: .5s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  bottom: 6px;
  color: #8792a1;
}

.container:focus-within #label {
  transform: translate3d(0, -26px, 0);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .99);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="input" value="" size="40" placeholder="Provincie">
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't move label to top when click the input field..

Comment: @RayeesAC yes it won't and I agree this not what OP needs, but I am giving better option, than making the text jumbled on the label(which is what yours doing now). and ofcourse I will take my answer out if OP don't need this :)