# Contact Form Not Working Correct - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I got it to work the way I wanted once, but cant seem to make it work again. This image shows my desired result, and then what's happening.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUCuN.png

Why is this happening?

This is the code that's working for me:

```
<div class="form">
  <input type="name" name="name" autocomplete="off" required />
  <label for="name" class="label-name"> 
      <span class="content-name"> Name </span>
```

And the CSS styling:

```
.content-name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.form input:focus + .label-name .content-name,
.form input:valid + .label-name .content-name {
  transform: translateY(-150%);
  color: #5fa8d3;
}

.form input:focus + .label-name::after,
.form input:valid + .label-name::after {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

Code that isn't working:

```
<div class="form"> 
    <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" required />
    <label for="name" class="label-email">
        <span class="content-email"> Email </span>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.content-email {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.form input:focus + .label-email .content-email,
.form input:valid + .label-email .content-email {
  transform: translateY(-150%);
  color: #5fa8d3;
}

.form input:focus + .label-email::after,
.form input:valid + .label-email::after {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

Comment: You need to hold the placeholder at the top when there is text in the input. Try this solution with javascript - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63548283/move-input-field-on-top-of-span/63548334#63548334

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this worked, I changed "email" to "emailaddress" in the div and its working fine now.